# How to show HTML elements at specific window widths?

Tags: php, html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I want to find a way to make hexagons be a good looking container for text at all window widths. At this point it only looks alright at a few window widths. I'd like to make it so that I can have code  that will only show at the good width then hide itself when the screen width changes to a new range so that a new piece of code that does look good can take its place. How am I to do this?

**My php code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css"href="css/styleshexagon.css">
                <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <!-- jQuery library -->
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <?php
                        //for Medium screen width
                        print"<div class = \" d-none d-md-block d-lg-none\"\>\n";
                        $numHexes=3;
                        for($i = 0;$i<$numHexes;$i++)
                        {
                                print"<div class=\"hexagon  \">\n";
                                print"  <span class=\"text\">XYZ</span>\n";
                                print"  </div>\n";
                        }
                        for($i = 0;$i<$numHexes;$i++)
                        {
                                print"<div class=\"hexagon \" style = \"
                                        margin-left:auto ;
                                        margin-bottom: auto;
                                        \">\n";
                                print"  <span class=\"text\">XYZ</span>\n";
                                print"</div>\n";
                        }
                        print"</div>\n";
                        //for Small screen width
                        /*Code for that goes here*/
                ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

**My SASS code:**

```
$hex-size: 300px;
$hex-height: $hex-size / sqrt(3);
$hex-color: #C6538C;


.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width: $hex-size;
  height: $hex-height;
  background-color: $hex-color;
  margin: $hex-height/2;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;
  left:-10px;

}

.hexagon .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  left: 0;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  color: #ff00ff;
  width: $hex-size;
  height: $hex-height;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: $hex-height;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: $hex-size/2 solid transparent;
  border-right: $hex-size/2 solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: $hex-height/2 solid $hex-color;
}

.hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: $hex-height/2 solid $hex-color;
}
```

Comment: have you used media queries?

Comment: use `d-none` `d-sm-block` `d-md-block` `d-lg-block` `d-xl-block` based on your requirement, no need to write custom media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your asking for a few different things here. Displaying only certain elements at certain screen sizes, and formatting elements so they are suitable for most if not all screen sizes.

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
.mydiv {
width: 100%; /* adds full width to mydiv which is best for mobiles */
display: block; /* displays mydiv as a block */
}
.mydiv-2 {
display: none; /* Doesn’t display mydiv-2 at screen sizes upto 700px  */
}
}
```

Note that you can use both `max-width` and `min-width`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for your helpful response! So in my implementation I would have multiple @media structures with  different max and min width's of the window size and that within those structures I can specify what they would look like? To be even more specific would it be correct to say that when I resize my browser window it would allow me to hide and show  different things?

Comment: I've done some experimenting and have found that this is the right solution! Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is correct. You can supply as many Media structures as you wish specific for certain size devices, but if you try to stick to using width:100% within your Media sizes then you should only require one for lets say 'Mobiles' as a whole, instead of creating one for iPhone 5, one for iPhone 6, one for Samsung Galaxy A5 etc.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use the `@media` [CSS rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) Which can apply different styling based on different display media. In your case, to customize based on screen size you could use the `min-width` and `max-width` properties.

This example would hide `someElement` if the screen was smaller than 200 pixels wide.

```
@media min-width: 200px {
    someElement {
        display: none
    }
}
```